# DISTINCT pulling duplicate column values

Tags: sql, join, distinct, inner-join

The following query is pulling duplicate `site_id`s, with me using DISTINCT I can't figure out why...

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT site_id,
    deal_woot.*,
    site.woot_off,
    site.name AS site_name
FROM deal_woot
INNER JOIN site ON site.id = site_id
WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
ORDER BY deal_woot.id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` looks at the *entire* record, not just the column directly after it. To accomplish what you want, you'll need to use `GROUP BY`:

**Non-working code:**

```
SELECT
    site_id,
    deal_woot.*,
    site.woot_off,
    site.name AS site_name
FROM deal_woot
INNER JOIN site ON site.id = site_id
WHERE site_id IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
GROUP BY site_id
```

Why doesn't it work? If you `GROUP BY` a column, you should use an aggregate function (such as `MIN` or `MAX`) on the rest of the columns -- otherwise, if there are multiple  `site_woot_off`s for a given `site_id`, it's not clear to SQL *which of those values* you want to `SELECT`.

You will probably have to expand `deal_woot.*` to list each of its fields.

Side-note: If you're using MySQL, I believe it's not technically necessary to specify an aggregate function for the remaining columns. If you don't specify an aggregate function for a column, it chooses a single column value for you (usually the first value in the result set).

Answer (score 2):

Your query is returning `DISTINCT` rows, it is not just looking at `site_id`. In other words, if any of the columns are different, a new row is returned from this query.

This makes sense, because if you actually do have differences, what should the server return as values for `deal_woot.*` ? If you want to do this, you need to specify this - perhaps done by getting distinct `site_id`'s, then getting `LIMIT 1` of the other values in a subquery with an appropiate `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: He seems to use Mysql, so it should be `LIMIT 1`, not `TOP 1`.

Comment: True if it really is MySql, but as far as I can tell the code sample would also be valid in MSSQL.

Comment: He has `LIMIT 5`, so it cannot be MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting distinct value from one table only. When you join with the other table it will pull all rows that match each of your distinct value from the other table, causing duplicate id's

Comment: ok, if something is wrong with my answer please explain. It will help me learn as well as others who read my answer...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe it was because of the wrong statement: `You are selecting distinct value from one table only`. Actually SELECT DISTINCT selects distinct *rows* from the *resulting set*.

Comment: ah, ok. I thought it took the beginning part as distinct first. my bad. i shall leave my error for posterity :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select site info and a single row from deal_woot table with the same site_id, you need to use a different query. For example,

```
SELECT site.id, deal_woot.*, site.woot_off, site.name
FROM site 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT site_id, MAX(id) as id FROM deal_woot 
     WHERE site_id IN (2,3,4,5,6) GROUP BY site_id) X 
ON (X.site_id = site.id)
INNER JOIN deal_woot ON (deal_woot.id = X.id)
WHERE site.id IN (2,3,4,5,6);
```

This query should work regardless of sql dialect/db vendor. For mysql, you can just add `group by site_id` to  your original query, since it lets you use `GROUP BY` without aggregate functions.
** I assume that `deal_woot.id` and `site.id` are primary keys for `deal_woot` and `site` tables respectively.